# Create food Mold using voronoi texture

Tags: node-editor

I am trying to figure our how to create food mold using voronoi texture.

A similar question was asked [procedurally generated mold (fungus) using voronoi texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142974/procedurally-generated-mold-fungus-using-voronoi-texture/184615?noredirect=1#comment309224_184615)

previously but I was hoping to get more insight on how it works. I tried setting up my nodes according to the screenshots from the link but it doesn't show the complete nodes graph

I have attached my node graph. I am confused with how to use the transparency node

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ULEH.jpg

Thank you

Comment: that appears to be the entire node tree in that answer. outside of the crop would be the coords and the output. Adding an image of your results and your node tree here would helpful, perhaps we can see the difference.

Comment: I added screenshot of my graph. I think my transparency node is messed up

Answer (score 2):

As Timaroberts mentioned in the comments, the entire graph is little more than shown in the image. Here it is with the most basic setup - note the blend modes I have highlighted on the right - these are necessary for transparency:

[image: Mold]

EDIT - This is the proper connections for the image you posted in the comments:

[image: Connections]

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you

Comment: My cycles render is now messing up the transparency. The whole model is transparent with the current node setup. Should I be using  Transparent BSDF material node instead?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why that's happening . It works fine in cycles on my end. No need to switch to transparent BSDF - Principled BSDF is essentially a "node network" containing multiple node features, including transparent shaders. Maybe try switching blend modes or clip threshold?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. So I am trying to combine the effect with my texture map.
In Cycles Render, the whole model is now transparent

https://imgur.com/a/6YU5sQy
It works fine with Evee Render

but in cycles, it looks like this
https://imgur.com/a/253GbFG

Am I not handling the transparency or blending with color map correctly?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your whole node setup. I'll post a pic of a working overlay with a texture to see if that helps.

Comment: Do me a favor first, connect the output of your black and white colorramp (the alpha) to the factor of your mix shader. It should work, but if it doesn't try the invert.

Comment: you are right it works. But how would I hook up the green color ramp of the mold now?

https://imgur.com/a/3JghPwe

That is my full node graph

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you should connect. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's working perfectly now! Thank you!